# When making a model using the entity designer (VS2010) how can I maintain the data?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

Because as I make small changes it regenerates the the entire DB and therefore removes the data..

I suppose I could manually maintain a script that I run that inserts the test data after I regenerate the schema.

Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87).

Comment: Kinda confusing .. but it seems to check the differences and make changes to your DB without removing the data.. or does it just create a script with your data  as well as the schema?